# TypeError 'str' objects is not callable - Python

Tags: python

I'm completely new to Python and i'm trying to write a program that essentially works as an alarm clock. I prompt the user for a specific time to set the alarm to and then when that time occurs, a youtube video taken from a list of youtube videos in a txt file will play. However, I'm not quite sure why i'm getting this error, as i'm still largely unfamiliar with python syntax. Here's my code:

```
import time

def addVideo():
    videoToAdd = raw_input("Enter the url of the video to add: ")
    with open('alarmVideos.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(videoToAdd + '\n')

alarmTime = raw_input("When would you like to set your alarm to?: \nPlease use this format: 01:00\n")

localTime = time.strftime("%H:%M") 

addVideo = raw_input("Would you like to add a video to your list? (y/n): \n")

if addVideo == 'y' or addVideo == 'n':
    addVideo()


print "Your alarm is set to:", alarmTime
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bkrause080\Desktop\Free Time Projects\LearningPythonProjects\alarmClock.py", line 15, in <module>
    addVideo()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

If it helps this error occurs after the user enters y/n to whether not not they want to add a video to their list. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You have a name conflict. Use another name for the string object so `addVideo` only refers to the function

Comment: You can't use `addVideo` for both a function name and another variable. Function names are variables too. Rename one or the other.

Comment: You are confusing Python. You are using **addVideo** as the name for a string variable as well as for the name of a function. Just use a different name for one of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is since you named both the function name and variable with the same name(addVideo),Python 'confuses' the function and variable.Rename any one of them:

```
import time

def addVideo():
    videoToAdd = raw_input("Enter the url of the video to add: ")
    with open('alarmVideos.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(videoToAdd + '\n')

alarmTime =raw_input("When would you like to set your alarm to?: \nPlease use this format: 01:00\n")

localTime = time.strftime("%H:%M")

add_Video = raw_input("Would you like to add a video to your list? (y/n): \n")

if add_Video == 'y' or add_Video == 'n':
    addVideo()


print( "Your alarm is set to:", alarmTime)
```

Output:

```
When would you like to set your alarm to?: 
Please use this format: 01:00

Would you like to add a video to your list? (y/n): 
n
Enter the url of the video to add: grg
Your alarm is set to:
```

Comment: ah thank you so much! I really only have experience with java and C so python's taking some getting used to!

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the function addVideo() with a string: `addVideo = raw_input("Would you like ...")`

You need to rename the function or the varaible.

```
addVideoResult = raw_input("Would...")

if addVideoResult == 'y' or addVideoResult == 'n':
    addVideo()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a different name reference for `raw_input("Would you like to add a video to your list? (y/n): \n")` since you are overriding the function:

```
run = raw_input("Would you like to add a video to your list? (y/n): \n")
if run == 'y' or run == 'n':
    addVideo()
```